# Is there a way to check if user has granted a given permission in server-side?

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, codeplex

I need to check if user has granted a given permission (for example: publish_stream) in server-side. It seams for client-side exists solution but what I need is for server-side.

Any idea please?

Answer (score 1):

You need a server side API like the [Facebook Java API](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api/) or [restFB](http://restfb.com/). These are java APIs (that I have used), there a host of others for different languages. The official ones are shown on the [Facebook developer portal](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdks/).

Using these APIs you will be able to do more than just authenticate a user on the server side. Follow the link to the different pages and you'll find snippets that will get you started in no time!

### EDIT

Since you're using ASP, you'll need an ASP .NET API. This is the first result found from a google search http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/ .

Using this API and an MVC architecture, you are able to annotate any controller actions that contain code that requires permissions with something like `[CanvasAuthorize(Perms = "publish_stream")]` and when the user calls that action they'll need to provide permission.

I cant give more details as I've never used this API but do check out this in-depth [tutorial on building a sample application](http://www.devx.com/MS_Azure/Article/46308?trk=DXRSS_LATEST#fbid=ZRxrB2Juw6q).

Comment: Actually I am using ASP.NET and user's authentication is not my problem.
I've written an application that provides some features. Each feature needs own permissions.
I need to check if user has granted a specific permission to allow him/her to use that specific feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a Graph API call to this URL https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions including the user access token. You will get results with the user's permissions. For more details see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Step 1. First u must make a query:
query is like: `SELECT {0} FROM permissions WHERE uid = {1}`

{0} is comma-separated permissions. for example: `publish_stream,offline_access`

{1} is userId

Step 2. Then send this query to the given url:

url: `https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query={0}&format=JSON&access_token={1}`

{0} is query that we made in step1

{1} is user's AccessToken

Sample Result: `[{"publish_stream":1,"offline_access":0}]`

**Update** Another way with using Graph Api:

`https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token={0}`

{0} is user's AccessToken

Sample Result:

{

"data": [

```
  {
     "installed": 1,
     "status_update": 1,
     "photo_upload": 1,
     "video_upload": 1,
     "offline_access": 1,
     "create_note": 1,
     "share_item": 1,
     "bookmarked": 1,
     "publish_stream": 1
  }
```

]
}